# Doesn't return all editors of my spreadsheet with the .getEditors function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-workspace

At my company we use Gsuite. We have a shared Drive with about ~80 colleagues.
By default, every colleague is also editor in all the spreadsheets in that drive folder. So in one of those spreadsheet, I try to get an overview of all the colleagues. I'm using this code. It does work fine, but it just returns only ~60 colleagues or so. And I can't figure out why that is.

```js
function getEditors()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var permissions = [];
  
  
  var  viewers = sheet.getEditors();
  
  Logger.log(viewers);
  
}
```

So far I can tell, everybody is an editor, just see the screenshot below.
[image]

And it's always the same colleagues that are missing.
Hope somebody can help me with this!

Comment: Any chance some have editing access through some group construct (i.e. have access as team members)? I had a similar weird behaviour a few months ago and that seemed to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your response! 
How would I be able to check this? And how did you solve it?

Comment: I was able to see it through the share screen (the one you have a screen shot of) and decided to treat the groups in the same way as individuals. Don't know if there's a size limit on the log though, have you tried listing the editors in a sheet to get the complete list?

Comment: Thanks @a-burge, I figured it out. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @a-burge I figured it out. Apparently I had to go to the settings in my shared Drive file, where I could see all the colleagues. There were a few who had 'Content manager' instead of 'Contributor' als a role. After changing this, it returned all the colleagues.

[image]